# Styling input labels in Foundation 5

Tags: css, zurb-foundation-5

I am using
[Foundation 5's "prefix" class](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/forms.html) to style labels for HTML input elements. The problem I am having, is that when the text inside of the label becomes too long (either because of the text's length or from resizing the browser window), the label begins to disappear, and allows the input element to take over the rest of the space.  This is the code I am using:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="large-6 columns">
        <div class="row collapse prefix-radius">
            <div class="small-3 columns">
                <span class="prefix">A Test Label</span>
            </div>
            <div class="small-9 columns">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Value">
            </div>
        </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

[Here is a jsfiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/a63kayuc/)

The behavior that I would like to have, is that all of the text on the label is always visible, and the input element becomes smaller (or hidden) if needed.

Bootstrap actually handles this situation exactly as I would like [(jsfiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/zkwm36y8/), but I need to emulate this behavior using Foundation.

Comment: Because in bootstrap the wrapper element  .input-group has a display:table, meaning that its children - td's are guaranteed to keep their content visible and label element has white-space:nowrap - content stays on one line. I didn't manage to find yet the same functionality in Foundation. seems like it needs manual css adjusting - http://jsfiddle.net/a63kayuc/1/

Answer (score 0):

You can adjust the column classes to specify different widths for different screen sizes.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="large-6 columns">
        <div class="row collapse prefix-radius">
            <div class="small-5 medium-4 large-3 columns">
                <span class="prefix">A Test Label</span>
            </div>
            <div class="small-7 medium 8 large-9 columns">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Value">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```